# Regarding User Account Password Expired

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise

I got the following error

> "There was an error encrypting or decrypting credentials. Either a
>   credential update is currently being performed, or you must update the
>   farm account credentials on this server before you can perform this
>   task."

I tried running

```
stsadm –o updatefarmcredentials –userlogin username –password password
```

but both the command prompt and powershell gives above error.
I have even tried changing passwords in services and IIS Manager but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a WSS 3.0 hotfix for that. It's a known bug. It's the 3rd to last bullet.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957691

Comment: Hi Mike, when I  tried to run the hotfix, it says "There are no products affected by this package installed on this system"

Comment: I got the solution. here it is http://sharepointspecialist.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/22/